# Invoke bash.exe through QProcess: kill does not kill subprocess

Tags: windows, bash, qt, pid, qprocess

On windows, I invoke bash.exe to run a long processing shell command such as *git lfs pull*, using a QProcess.
In fact, the call looks like this:

```
process->start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "git lfs pull");
```

and it is spawning a bash.exe as well as a git-lfs.exe, as expected. However, calling

```
process->kill()
```

kills the bash process but the bash fails to kill the git-lfs process.
I also tried to use *terminate* instead, but no luck as well.
Frankly, there must be a way to do this as calling

```
bash -c git lfs pull
```

on CMD works as expected, killing git-lfs.exe when quitting the CMD.

I could not find a way to signal SIGINT to the bash.exe to emulate the CTRL+C behaviour.
I also experimented with invoking a cmd process like so

```
process->start("cmd", QStringList() << "/c" << "bash -c 'git lfs pull'");
```

but the issue remains.

Another idea I had was to collect all PPIDs through *bash -c ps* but then I am missing the connection from the bash process ID to the QProcess pid.
There must be a smarter way to approach this issue, I hope?

Comment: exec your child process in job and terminate job

Comment: thanks a lot for making me aware of this feature. Issuing the command as 'git lfs pull &' and killing it with 'kill %1' does the trick. Please post an answer so that I can accept it